# Convert hex to 15 bit RGB value in python

Tags: python, rgb, bit-shift

im a beginner with python and want to make a program that converts a hex RGB value to a 15 bit RGB one (5 bits for every color) i heard that it can be done by bitshifts but i don´t get how i also didn´t find anything helpful on the internet can someone please help me

Comment: This is not a specific enough question. What kind of data is your input formatted as, and what kind of format would you want from your output

Comment: Hi @LordMZTE. I work for an LED lighting company and we love using the Colour Science Python library for stuff like this. https://github.com/colour-science/colour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're doing this manually (say, for homework), think of the problem like this:

If you have a six character hex representation of a color (`"7FD87F"` for instance), it's made up of the RGB components R: 7F, G: D8, B: 7F.

Two hexadecimal digits can encode 256 different states (16^2 = 256), so each of these components is 8 bits in size (256 = 2^8).

You want to transform your value into a color space where each component is represented in 5 bits. The way to do this is to throw away the three least significant bits from each of the components. For example:

```
0b10101010 => 0b10101
```

As you correctly mentioned, you would do this via bit-shifting. You'll then need to recombine the components. As a hint, here's how I would recombine the original 8-bit components into a single 24-bit representation:

```
(R << 16) + (G << 8) + (B << 0) 
# or just B since a shift by zero is equivalent to
# multiplying by 2^0 is
# multiplying by 1 is
# the multiplicative identity
```

So the sketch of your algorithm, assuming you are starting with a hex string and not an integer:

1. Split the hex string into individual color components
2. Convert the string representations to numeric representations
3. Bit shift the components
4. Recombine the 5-bit components into a 15-bit representation

Additionally, steps 1 and 2 are interchangible with some bit-masking and a little more bit-shifting.